# Multiple independent singleton routes within cluster

Tags: java, apache-camel, cluster-computing, jgroups

I'm referring to the chapter "Keeping singleton route within the cluster" on Camel's documentation about JGroups.

I successfully implemented a singleton route within a cluster in the way described in the beforementioned chapter. But now I need to provide the same functionality in multiple, independent (for example within different WARs) routes.

The first route builder configures

- the first actual route and
- the route that starts the actual route via controlbus component if it is on the live server.

But the second route builder that tries to configure the route that starts the second actual route via controlbus component fails because there is already a consumer listening on the JGroups endpoint and that endpoint does not implement the MultipleConsumersSupport.

What would be the right way to start multiple routes, each configured in separate route builders which themselves reside possibly in different WARs, as singletons?

Answer (score 0):

I still can't tell whether this is "the right way" to start multiple routes, but at least I found a way that works.

Summary: apply message routing pattern 'recipient list' as described in http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

A bit more detailed: I mainly had to replace this starter route definition (starting route with ID `routeId` on live node only)

```
from("jgroups:clusterName?enableViewMessages=true")
  .filter(JGroupsFilters.dropNonCoordinatorViews())
  .threads().delay(JGroupsExpressions.delayIfContextNotStarted(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)))
  .to("controlbus:route?routeId=" + routeId + "&action=start&async=true");
```

with this starter route definition

```
from("jgroups:clusterName?enableViewMessages=true")
  .filter(JGroupsFilters.dropNonCoordinatorViews())
  .threads().delay(JGroupsExpressions.delayIfContextNotStarted(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)))
  .bean(dynamicRecipientList);
```

and for every route (again with ID `routeId`) to be started

```
dynamicRecipientList.get().add("direct:" + routeId);
from("direct:" + routeId)
  .to("controlbus:route?routeId=" + routeId + "&action=start&async=true");
```

where dynamicRecipientList could be an instance of something like this

```
public class DynamicRecipientList {

  private List<String> recipients = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<String> get() { return recipients; }

  @RecipientList public List<String> get(String body) { return recipients; }
}
```

Comments and suggestions for improvement still welcome!